# iPhone Facebook app not showing a link when displaying application name on a wall posting made by iOS app

Tags: ios, mobile, facebook-ios-sdk, photos

I have written an iPhone app that includes a feature to share images with facebook.  It uses the following code to post images to the users wall.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               img, @"picture",
                               photoItem.caption == nil ? @"" :
                               photoItem.caption,@"name", nil];        

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

It posts the photo up on the wall with no problems.  When viewing the wall with Facebook on a desktop computer, the app name is a link that takes you to the facebook app page.

When viewing the same posting on the iPhone or Android facebook app, the app name is no longer a link.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug or by design?